# Button instance in html file not loaded when code runs for my incremental game

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ecmascript-6, frontend

I am creating an incremental game with `JavaScript` and `html`, and I'm having an issue where some html button elements are not loading while I'm running certain code.

This is my main JavaScript file:

```
import Store from "./store.js";

window.onload = ()=>{

    let fishCount = 0;
    let lifeTimeFishCount = 0;
    let cps = 0;
    //cookies per click
    let cpc = 1;

    const fishCountSite = document.getElementById("fishCount");
    const cpsSite = document.getElementById("fpsCounter");
    const goFishing = document.getElementById("fishBtn");
    const storeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("buyBtn");

    let store = new Store();

    function onClick() {
      fishCount += cpc;
      lifeTimeFishCount += cpc;
      return fishCount;
    }

    function main() {
      goFishing.addEventListener("click", function() {
        onClick();
        fishCountSite.innerHTML = fishCount;
      });
      store.store(fishCount, storeBtns);
    }

    main();

}
```

This is the store.js file:

```
export default class Store {
    constructor() {
      this.fishPole = {
        price: 50,
        cps: 0.5,
        amount: 0
      };

      this.net = {
        price: 300,
        cps: 2,
        amount: 0
      };

      this.boat = {
        price: 2500,
        cps: 15,
        amount: 0
      };

      this.crew = {
        price: 21000,
        cps: 120,
        amount: 0
      };

      this.yacht = {
        price: 180000,
        cps: 900,
        amount: 0
      };

      this.factory = {
        price: 1000000,
        cps: 8000,
        amount: 0
      };

      this.portal = {
        price: 10000000,
        cps: 70000,
        amount: 0
      };
    }

    test(fishCount){
      if(fishCount >= this.fishPole.price){
        console.log("enough money to buy fishing pole");
      }
    }

    store(fishCount, storeBtns) {
      storeBtns[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.test();
      });
    }
  }
```

This is the main index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Fish Game</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link real="stylesheet" href=".src/styles.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="title">
      <img src="./src/images/fish.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Fish Game</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="app">
      <div class="fishPole">
        <img src="./src/images/fishingrod2.png" alt="" id="fishPole" />
      </div>
      <div class="fishBtn">
        <button type="button" id="fishBtn">Go Fishing!</button>
      </div>
      <div class="fishCount">
        <div id="fishCountLabel">Fish Count:</div>
        <div id="fishCount">0</div>
        <div id="fpsCounter">FPS: 0</div>
      </div>
      <div class="store">
        <div id="storeName">Bait Shop</div>
        <div id="storeFront"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="app2">
      <div class="structures">
        <div id="structureLabel">Structures</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="app3">
      <div class="structureStore">
        <div id="structureStoreTitle">Store</div>
        <div id="fishingPole" class="structureStoreItems">Fishing Pole
          <button type="button" class="buyBtn" id="fishingPoleBtn">Buy</button>
        </div>
        <div id="net" class="structureStoreItems">???
          <button type="button" class="buyBtn" id="netBtn">Buy</button>
        </div>
        <div id="boat" class="structureStoreItems">???
          <button type="button" class="buyBtn" id="boatBtn">Buy</button>
        </div>
        <div id="crew" class="structureStoreItems">???
          <button type="button" class="buyBtn" id="crewBtn">Buy</button>
        </div>
        <div id="yacht" class="structureStoreItems">???
          <button type="button" class="buyBtn" id=yachtBtn>Buy</button>
        </div>
        <div id="fishFactory" class="structureStoreItems">???
          <button type="button" class="buyBtn" id="fishFactoryBtn">Buy</button>
        </div>
        <div id="fishPortal" class="structureStoreItems">???
          <button type="button" class="buyBtn" id="fishPortalBtn">Buy</button>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="./src/index.js" type="module"></script>
</html>
```

When I run this using the http-server node package or in codesandbox.io, and press the button I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: this.test is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (store.js:57)` I posted about this issue before and the solution I was given was to wrap my `index.js` file in `window.onload`. I did this but im still having the same issue. I've looked over my main `index.html` file and cannot find anything wrong with it. I've been troubleshooting this for a while and am getting nowhere. Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the anonymous function you're declaring inside the `store` function is not bound to the class context and therefore cannot access `this`. `this` instead refers to the function itself. This can be solved by using an arrow function which do not have their own context.

You should replace your `store` implementation with the following:

```js
store(fishCount, storeBtns) {
    storeBtns[0].addEventListener("click", () => {
        this.test();
    });
}
```

Or you could do the following:

```js
store(fishCount, storeBtns) {
    storeBtns[0].addEventListener("click", function {
        this.test();
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Or even

```js
store(fishCount, storeBtns) {
    storeBtns[0].addEventListener("click", this.test);
}
```